# Apache can serve files in root, but not in any subfolder

Tags: firefox, apache2, drupal

Brand new LAMP installation on Ubuntu 14.04.

I can view all of the files at the root /var/www/html/ folder. I can run phpinfo.php at the root. I installed phpmyadmin and can access that application.

I just can't access any subfolder of /var/www/html . I have tried viewing a simple html file, but it still gives me the error. The error Firefox gives me is:
Unable to connect

Firefox can't establish a connection to the server at localhost.

```
The site could be temporarily unavailable or too busy. Try again in a few moments.
If you are unable to load any pages, check your computer's network connection.
If your computer or network is protected by a firewall or proxy, make sure that Firefox is permitted to access the Web.
```

I have checked the permissions of the folders, and they are drwxr-xr-x, just like the html folder, and the files in the subfolder are -rw-r--r--, just like the files in the html folder.

One more thing: The subfolder is running Drupal 7.31. The first time I tried to access the subfolder, it gave me an error that it cannot access the database. I then created the database, using the db configuration in the sites/default/settings.php file. Since then I have been getting the "Unable to connect" error message. The non-drupal subfolders also give me the same error.

Can you please let me know how I can access these files?

Comment: In doing more research, I have found that Apache is redirecting http: //localhost/subfolder to http**s**://localhost/subfolder . I have checked the .htaccess file and commented out the redirect there, but it is still redirecting. Do I need to make a change elsewhere or clear a cache somewhere?

Comment: did you restart Apache?

Comment: Yes, I restarted Apache.

Comment: Did you try it with other browsers too? I have a similar issue in Firefox, but it works perfectly in Chrome.